# Arduino Serial.print() if Weight is Steady

Tags: arduino

I have a code in Arduino that runs a height and weight sensor combination with an ultrasonic sensor and load cells. I need the weights and heights to print to the serial monitor only when the weight has been steady on the scale for three seconds and the same for the height. What I mean by steady is that the weight or height would have to be the same for three seconds. Is this possible?

**The code that I have for the circuit is as follows:**

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

#define calibration_factor -13180.00

//This value is obtained using the SparkFun_HX711_Calibration sketch

#define DOUT  7
#define CLK  6

HX711 scale(DOUT, CLK);

LiquidCrystal LCD(10, 9, 5, 4, 3, 2);  //Create Liquid Crystal Object 
called LCD

int trigPin=13; //Sensor Trip pin connected to Arduino pin 13
int echoPin=11;  //Sensor Echo pin connected to Arduino pin 11
int myCounter=0;  //declare your variable myCounter and set to 0
int servoControlPin=6; //Servo control line is connected to pin 6
float pingTime;  //time for ping to travel from sensor to target and return
float targetDistance; //Distance to Target in inches
float speedOfSound=776.5; //Speed of sound in miles per hour when temp is 77 degrees.


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("HX711 scale demo");

  scale.set_scale(calibration_factor); //This value is obtained by 
  using the SparkFun_HX711_Calibration sketch
  scale.tare(); //Assuming there is no weight on the scale at start up, reset the scale to 0

  Serial.println("Readings:");

  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);

  LCD.begin(16,2); //Tell Arduino to start your 16 column 2 row LCD
  LCD.setCursor(0,0);  //Set LCD cursor to upper left corner, column 0, row 0
  LCD.print("Target Distance:"); 

}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Reading: ");
  Serial.print(scale.get_units(), 1); //scale.get_units() returns a float
  Serial.print(" lbs"); //You can change this to kg but you'll need to refactor the calibration_factor
  Serial.println();

  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); //Set trigger pin low
  delayMicroseconds(2000); //Let signal settle
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH); //Set trigPin high
  delayMicroseconds(15); //Delay in high state
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); //ping has now been sent
  delayMicroseconds(10); //Delay in high state

  pingTime = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);  //pingTime is presented in microceconds
  pingTime=pingTime/1000000; //convert pingTime to seconds by dividing by 1000000 (microseconds in a second)
  pingTime=pingTime/3600; //convert pingtime to hourse by dividing by 3600 (seconds in an hour)
  targetDistance= speedOfSound * pingTime;  //This will be in miles, since speed of sound was miles per hour
  targetDistance=targetDistance/2; //Remember ping travels to target and back from target, so you must divide by 2 for actual target distance.
  targetDistance= targetDistance*63360;    //Convert miles to inches by multipling by 63360 (inches per mile)

  LCD.setCursor(0,1);  //Set cursor to first column of second row
  LCD.print("                "); //Print blanks to clear the row
  LCD.setCursor(0,1);   //Set Cursor again to first column of second row
  LCD.print(targetDistance); //Print measured distance
  LCD.print(" inches");  //Print your units.
  delay(250); //pause to let things settle

  Serial.print(targetDistance); 
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print(" inches "); 
  delay(250);


}
```

Comment: yes, of course this is possible,  question is, what do you mean steady on the scale for 3 seconds.    Do you want to monitor the loadcells till they look steady?  ie, the standard deviation is within a tolerance?  or are you simply going to take a reading after 3 seconds? or are you going to sample for 3 seconds and calculate a weight?

Comment: @KeithNicholas What I meant by steady was the same weight. For example, if my weight was the same on a scale for three seconds then I would know that there isn't weight changing and it is the correct weight.

Comment: that would be a sliding window of 3 seconds with a low std deviation, so you'd need >20 samples over 3 seconds

Comment: @KeithNicholas Thank You! By chance could you explain how to do this? Thanks!